# echo in inf-ruby

Tags: ruby, emacs

I am trying to get inf-ruby to work in Emacs.  For the most part it works fine, except for the very annoying habit of echoing every input entered.  Does anyone know what could be wrong?

I am using Carbon Emacs on OSX 10.5 with the default Ruby 1.8.6.  My irb version is 0.9.5

The odd bit is that inf-ruby worked perfectly one time I opened it, but I can't figure out what I did differently that single time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your init.el

```
;;

(defun echo-false-comint ()
(setq comint-process-echoes t))

(add-hook  ’comint-mode-hook  ’echo-false-comint)

;;
```

A little more explanation is on my [blog post](http://currentricity.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/removing-echo-in-irb-while-running-in-emacs/).

Comment: That did it thanks.

I made a slight modification, so it sets the echo flag only for inf-ruby mode.  In case something uses comint and needs the echos:
(add-hook 'inf-ruby-mode-hook 'echo-false-comint)